# Trying to understand the length of the list [PYTHON]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm studying python and at the moment I'm focusing on Lists.
The book that I'm reading for it, uses this code as example for creating a third list it doesn't repeat elements that exists in both lists:

```
first = []
second = []
while True:
    e = int(input("Enter a value for the first list (0 to end):")) 
    if e==0:
        break
    first.append(e)
while True:
    e = int(input("Enter a value for the second list (0 to finish):")) 
    if e==0:
        break
    second.append(e)
third = []

two_lists = first[:]
two_lists.extend(second)
x=0
while x < len(two_lists):
    y = 0
    while y < len(third): #**THIS LINE IS MY QUESTION**
        if two_lists[x] == third[y]:
            break;
        y=y+1
    if y == len(third):
        third.append(two_lists[x])
    x=x+1
x=0
while x < len(third):
    print(third[x])
    x=x+1
```

So, when he says *while y < len(third)* I don't understand why the len(third) is 1 and not 0, since third is set empty before the while part. Is there's something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: `third` starts as an empty list (not set) but it is populated during the iterations of the outer loop

Comment: btw, this is really not pythonic code

Comment: Friendly suggestion:  Find a new book.  QUICK!  Go.  Now.

Comment: Instead of making your life hard with user input code, I would suggest developing and testing with a couple of pre-defined lists, e.g. `first = [1, 2, 3]`. (by the way, your question is tagged `python`, no need to put `[PYTHON]` in the title) - On the first iteration, that loop is skipped, but once stuff is added to `third`, it can run.

Comment: As @Chris_Rands said this is not Pythonic code, and as S3DEV suggested, I encourage you to find another source to learn from

Comment: In addition to using canned strings for test (and posting that code here), include what the final list should be. I can't figure out what the goal is here.

Comment: @tdelaney - I was just about to post the SAME thing.  I've played around with the code and can't for the life of me see the point, nor the lesson this is trying (and failing!) to teach ...

Comment: I think the short answer is `third = set(first) | set(second)`

Comment: Yeah, @S3DEV, I'm not liking the book as well. I just bought another two books from different authors to replace this one. Thanks for the tips, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first iteration of the loop at line 18, `len(third)` is indeed `0` and *not* `1`.

So we don't get into the while loop of line 20, but instead, get into the `if` clause at line 24, only from that part on `len(third)` would be positive.

Comment: Oooh! I get it! I thought that he would jump the while loop and go straight to second while loop, on line 28.

Answer (score 0):

That is true the first time it comes to that while loop.

However, the outer loop populates the third list.

Comment: wrong in several ways, python lists are mutable and an empty list is of length 0

Comment: Consider: `l = []`, then `len(l)`, will be 0.  Then, `l.append(1)`.  You'll find that lists **are** mutable and an empty list has the length 0.

Answer (score 0):

the length of third for the initial iteration should be 0 so that whole while loop will be jumped.
Then the following if statement will test true as 0 is equal to 0 and an element would then be added to your third array.